# conky causes xorg high cpu usage - ati/radeon acceleration issue

Tags: linux, drivers, cpu, xorg, conky

I'm running debian jessie and lately switched from fglrx video driver to free ati radeon driver. I've managed to set it up but I've noticed xorg is causing high CPU load: 30-50%.
Googling a little bit, looking at htop and turning off processes I've found that conky is causing that xorg high CPU usage. Default `/etc/conky.conf` is OK and CPU load stays no higher than 2%.
My custom `~/.conkyrc` worked fine and did not caused that high CPU load on fglrx 15.9 driver. So I presume that free radeon driver does not like some settings.
I attach my `~/.conkyrc` below. Maybe someone could look at it and tell me what am I missing?

Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
X server: X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Radeon module version: 7.5.0
Conky version: 1.9.0-6

```
# conky configuration
background no
use_xft yes
xftfont DejaVu Sans Mono:size=8
xftalpha 1
out_to_console no
update_interval 1 
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
minimum_size 300 760
maximum_width 300
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
borders 10
border_inner_margin 0
default_color white
default_shade_color black
default_outline_color white
#alignment top_left
alignment top_right
#alignment bottom_left
#alignment bottom_right
gap_x 4
gap_y 5
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2
override_utf8_locale yes
if_up_strictness link
use_spacer left

TEXT
${color green}${time %a, }${color }${time %Y-%m-%d}${alignr}${color green}${time %Z, }${color }${time %H:%M:%S}  
${color green}UpTime: ${color }${alignr}$uptime  
${color green}Kern:${color }${alignr}$kernel  
${color green}CPU0:${color }${cpu cpu0}% ${acpitemp}°C ${goto 153}${color green}CPU1:${color }${cpu cpu1}% ${acpitemp}°C  
${color dimgrey}${cpugraph cpu0 20,149 006400 00ff00} ${goto 153}${cpugraph cpu1 20,149 006400 00ff00}  
${color green}Load: ${color }$loadavg  
${color green}Processes: ${color }$processes  
${color green}Running:   ${color }$running_processes  

${color green}Top CPU: ${goto 153}${color green}Top MEM:  
${color yellow}${top name 1}${top cpu 1}${goto 153}${color yellow}${top_mem name 1}${top_mem mem 1}  
${color lightgrey}${top name 2}${top cpu 2}${goto 153}${color lightgrey}${top_mem name 2}${top_mem mem 2}  
${color lightgrey}${top name 3}${top cpu 3}${goto 153}${color lightgrey}${top_mem name 3}${top_mem mem 3}  
${color lightgrey}${top name 4}${top cpu 4}${goto 153}${color lightgrey}${top_mem name 4}${top_mem mem 4}  

${color green}MEM: ${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${membar 11,150}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}$mem/$memmax${goto 170}${memperc}%  
${color green}${voffset 2}SWAP:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${swapbar 11,150}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}$swap/$swapmax${goto 170}${swapperc}%  

${color green}HDD:${color }${diskio_read /dev/sda} ${goto 153}${diskio_write /dev/sda} ${alignr}${hddtemp}°C  
${color dimgrey}${diskiograph_read /dev/sda 20,149 006400 00ff00 100000} ${goto 153}${diskiograph_write 20,149 006400 00ff00 100000}  
${color green}ROOT:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${fs_bar 11,150 /}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}${fs_size /}/${fs_free /}${goto 170}${fs_used_perc /}%${goto 200}  
${color green}${voffset 2}USR:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${fs_bar 11,150 /usr}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}${fs_size /usr}/${fs_free /usr}${goto 170}${fs_used_perc /usr}%${goto 200}  
${color green}${voffset 2}VAR:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${fs_bar 11,150 /var}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}${fs_size /var}/${fs_free /var}${goto 170}${fs_used_perc /var}%${goto 200}  
${color green}${voffset 2}TMP:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${fs_bar 11,150 /tmp}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}${fs_size /tmp}/${fs_free /tmp}${goto 170}${fs_used_perc /tmp}%${goto 200}  
${color green}${voffset 2}HOME:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${fs_bar 11,150 /home}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}${fs_size /home}/${fs_free /home}${goto 170}${fs_used_perc /home}%${goto 200}  
${color green}${voffset 2}DATA:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${fs_bar 11,150 /mnt/data}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}${fs_size /mnt/data}/${fs_free /mnt/data}${goto 170}${fs_used_perc /mnt/data}%${goto 200}  

${if_up wlan0}${color green}NET: ${color yellow}wlan0 ${alignr}${addrs wlan0}  
${color }${color red}Down: ${color }${downspeedf wlan0} KiB/s${goto 153}${color royalblue}Up: ${color }${upspeedf wlan0} KiB/s  
${color dimgrey}${downspeedgraph wlan0 20,149 8b0000 ff0000 6104}${goto 153}${upspeedgraph wlan0 20,149 00008b 4169e1 1221}${else}${voffset -13}${endif}  
${if_up eth0}${color green}NET: ${color yellow}eth0 ${alignr}${addrs eth0}  
${color }${color red}Down: ${color }${downspeedf eth0} KiB/s${goto 153}${color royalblue}Up: ${color }${upspeedf eth0} KiB/s  
${color dimgrey}${downspeedgraph eth0 20,149 8b0000 ff0000 6104}${goto 153}${upspeedgraph eth0 20,149 00008b 4169e1 6104}${else}${voffset -13}${endif}  
${if_up ppp0}${color green}NET: ${color yellow}ppp0 ${alignr}${addrs ppp0}  
${color }${color red}Down: ${color }${downspeedf ppp0} KiB/s${goto 153}${color royalblue}Up: ${color }${upspeedf ppp0} KiB/s  
${color dimgrey}${downspeedgraph ppp0 20,149 8b0000 ff0000 64}${goto 153}${upspeedgraph ppp0 20,149 00008b 4169e1 64}${else}${voffset -13}${endif}  

${color green}BAT0:${color dimgrey}${goto 50}${battery_bar 11,150 BAT0}  
${color }${voffset -13}${goto 60}${battery_short BAT0}${alignr}${battery_time BAT0}
```

Comment: if the driver is slow then the driver is slow. make your conky window smaller for lower xorg usage.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your comment was not actual answer but gave me a hint. I dug deeper into `man radeon` and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI (debian wiki is rather enigmatic or outdated: still recommends EXA for performance tunning), looked at `Xorg.0.log` and found the reason:
Xorg auto detection loads EXA acceleration method for pre-TAHITI GPUs (mine is ARUBA). And - indeed - EXA is slow.

So, the solution is custom `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-radeon.conf` which loads `glamor` acceleration method:

```
Section "Device"  
    Identifier  "Radeon"  
    Driver "radeon"  
    Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"  
    Option "DRI" "3"  
    Option "TearFree" "on"  
EndSection
```

NOTE: I've found some articles that DRI3 requires Xorg version 1.17 or higher and ati/radeon driver 7.6 or higher so don't be surprised if it doesn't work.
Now Xorg is using no more than 2% CPU. Problem solved.